# Flutter web page not rendering after refresh

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I have been stuck with this issue some time now and feel I have tried everything, so really hope someone can give me some insight.

My problem is that my flutter application not renders when refreshing the page. The page loads properly when restarting or hot reloading the page.

I have tried to narrow it down by outcommenting my code and just something completety standard and doing all possible changes to that, but the problem still occurs. When creating a new project the problem isn't present, but if I copy over the code from the main file the problem is still there. So the issue must be somewhere else. Have tried to upgrade flutter and all sort of things, so need some suggestions on what the issue might be.
My code in the main file is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
// import 'package:frontend/utils/constants.dart';
// import 'package:frontend/view_model/auth_view_model.dart';
// import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
// import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
// import 'firebase_options.dart';
// import 'package:frontend/app_router.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

// Future<void> main() async {
//   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
//   await dotenv.load(fileName: '.env');

//   await Firebase.initializeApp(
//     options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
//   );

//   runApp(MyApp());

//   // runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
//   //   ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuthViewModel()),
//   // ], child: MyApp()));
// }

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Text('Hello World'),
    );
    // return MaterialApp(
    //   title: 'MathNote',
    //   theme: ThemeData(
    //     primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    //   ),
    //   onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.generateRoute,
    //   initialRoute: homeRoute,
    // );
  }
}
```

The full repo can be found at https://github.com/christianjensen2903/Math-Editor/frontend